# should rel-canonical also include protocol (http/https)?

Tags: html, seo, rel

I'm migrating my website from http to https (although it will still support access via http)

Currently all of my pages have accurate rel-canonical meta tags set in the HTML, but obviously they all point to the canonical http:// url.

Should I now be updating those to https:// too, or is it ok to leave them as http?

I'm wondering whether Google will penalise me, or start detecting duplicate content, if I start mixing them

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice (about how Google rates something). It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Fair enough. When I asked the question I felt it was related to the HTML RFC, but was struggling to find concrete info. I've since learn that rel-canonical is more of a search engine extension, so you're right, it probably doesn't belong here, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Google sees http and https as different sites so you should update them.

A redirect on the server might be sufficient in the short term but personally I would be looking to update the pages as soon as you can.