# incorrect pages found in sitemap.xml

Tags: wordpress, xml-sitemap

What is this issue?

The canonical tag for https://hwxcbd.com/nano-cbd-a-real-thing-or-a-marketing-gimmick/ this url is given bellow.

Please let me know how to fix this. Is it the http & https difference the main issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egDTs.png)

Comment: I'm not so sure but I can see that the canonical URL inside the page is in HTTP but in the sitemap is in HTTPS. This might cause the issue. But still, in the image the error is 'NON-canonical URL' which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained so you need to include all the relevant information, as external links can change or break over time and make the question unhelpful to other users. Please edit your question to include what is showing as the canonical URL in your html page, and any other relevant information that might help us to hel pyou find the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [should rel-canonical also include protocol (http/https)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690897/should-rel-canonical-also-include-protocol-http-https)

Comment: Yes Partially it does.
Thank you.